# Tables inspiration, any advice?

Tags: tables

This question might be a little bit subjective, but I am looking for inspiration of how I could tweak this table (It is a confusion matrix)? (I don't like the layout)
Do you have any advice?

This is how it looks:

[image]

```
    \documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

   \begin{table}[]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{l|l|c|c|c}
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{References}&\\
        \cline{3-4}
        \multicolumn{2}{c|}{}&witht&Non&\multicolumn{1}{c}{}\\
        \cline{2-4}
        \multirow{Predictions}& witht & 34269 & 67101 & \\
        \cline{2-4}
        & Non & 2969 & 9053 & \\
        \cline{2-4}
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Actual} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$38074$} & \multicolumn{ 1}{c}{$76154$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$$}\\
        \end{tabular}           
    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: please, gives us a context of this table in form of a complete but small document, which we can compile as it is and which provide page layout of your document.

Comment: Please, correct you code that it will become compilable.

Comment: @Zarko It is a confusion matrix, I edited my post

Comment: @Zarko the code is compilable?

Comment: no, you not add needed packages. also in code is some error. Please test your MWE yourself.

Comment: @Zarko I added the output of my code, but CarLaTeX's sollution solved my problem, as indicated i used a table generator and maybe there something went wrong

Comment: This not mean that there is not possible other solutions nor that you not need to correct your question!

Comment: @Zarko do have a suggestion of what i should change?

Comment: I already told you in one of my previous comment. just test you code (MWE) and see errors. Correct this errors (add missing packages at least).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your table doesn't seem human-made, it's very likely it's the output of some tool.

However, there are some errors.

The syntax of `\multirow` is `\multirow{number rows}{width}{text}` (using * as width in the multirow command, the text argument’s natural width is used, see https://texblog.org/2012/12/21/multi-column-and-multi-row-cells-in-latex-tables/), you missed the first two arguments (hence, it is not clear if "Predictions" should be at center of 2 or 3 rows).

Moreover, you defined 5 columns but only 4 have values.

Since the standard for professional tables says to avoid vertical rules, this is my suggestion (with my supposition about the position of "Prediction"):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htb]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{llrr}
        \toprule         
        &&\multicolumn{2}{c}{References}\\
        \cmidrule{3-4}
        &&\multicolumn{1}{c}{witht}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Non}\\
        \midrule
        \multirow{2}{*}{Predictions}& witht & 34269 & 67101 \\
        & Non & 2969 & 9053  \\
        \midrule
        Actual & & 38074 & 76154\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}           
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I indeed used a table generator for it. This looks awesome thank you!

Comment: @jenniferruurs You're welcome! Thank you for accepting my answer!

Answer (score 4):

another possibilities ...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makecell, multirow}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\mcc{O{1}m}
    {\multicolumn{#1}{c}{#2}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
\setcellgapes{5pt}
\makegapedcells
\sisetup{group-four-digits}
    \begin{tabular}{ll *{2}{S[table-format=5.0]}}
\mcc[2]{}       & \mcc[2]{References}   \\
        \cline{2-4}
\multirow{2.4}{*}{Predictions}
    & width     & 34269 & 67101         \\    
%        \cline{2-4}
    & Non       & 2969  & 9053          \\
        \cline{2-4}
\mcc{Actual}  
    & \mcc{}    &\mcc{\tablenum[table-format=5.0]{38074}}   
                        & \mcc{\tablenum[table-format=5.0]{76154}}  \\
        \cline{2-4}
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]